# Excel.Application.Workbooks collection does not contain workbook open from onedrive

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have two open workbooks. One from a standard filesystem folder, and one from my onedrive for business folder (which is really sharepoint 365)

When I do the following:

```
Excel.Application app = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

foreach(Excel.Workbook workbook in app.Workbooks)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(workbook.Name);
}
```

Only the workbook opened from my local folder is found and `Workbooks.Count == 1`.

So how can I get the workbook which was opened from my onedrive folder?  I need to be able to attach to this open workbook but seems the traditional methods do not work if the file is stored on sharepoint 365

Comment: How was the workbook on SharePoint opened in Excel on the local machine? I *suspect* what's happening is that it was opened in a *different instance* of Excel. If you go to either Excel's View and select Switch Windows I'm guessing the other workbook isn't listed? That would substantiate my surmise. GetActiveObject queries the Windows ROT; Office applications list only ONE application instance in the ROT, any others aren't there. If you look in Task Manager you'll probably also see two Excel processes?

Comment: Actually you are correct, I've since discovered this to be true.  I found a nice project on Code Project called Automate multiple Excel instances which gives me the tools to get the workbook I want.  If you repost as answer, I will mark it so.

Comment: Actually, I think what you found would make a much better answer :-) One I can point people at that need to work with multiple instances of an Office application. (We feel it's important to have all relevant information locally, on SO - you never know when other material may disappear! But if you feel you've "copied" a lot from the other source, add an acknowledgement and link to it.) You're more than welcome to include content from my "guess" as part of your answer. "Ping" me when you're done and I'll upvote it - I consider it that important to have on the site :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue on Code Project. A project by JamesFaix called [Automate multiple Excel instances.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1157395/Automate-multiple-Excel-instances)

There were only a couple of code snips I required from this project to accomplish my task of finding and binding to a running Excel workbook. I'll detail these here, but this is not my work so please check out the source article.  Using the code detailed below I am now able to get hold of a given instance of an excel workbook thus:

```
private bool TryGetOpenWorkbook(out Excel.Workbook workbook)
{
bool workbookFound = false;
workbook = null;

foreach (Process excelProcesses in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = excelProcesses.AsExcelApp();
    foreach (Excel.Workbook wb in excelApp.Workbooks)
    {
        if (wb.Name.Equals(_workbookName))
        {
            workbook = wb;
            workbookFound = true;
        }
    }
    // Release Process
    excelApp.ReleaseComObject();
    excelProcesses.ReleaseComObject();
}

return workbookFound;
}
```

First of the is an extension method on `System.Diagnostics.Process` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the Excel instance running in the given process, or null if none exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="process">The process.</param>
public static Excel.Application AsExcelApp(this Process process)
{
    if (process == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(process));

    var handle = process.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
    var result = NativeMethods.AppFromMainWindowHandle(handle);
    //Debug.Assert(result != null);
    return result;
}
```

Then a few static methods:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
private const string USER32 = "User32.dll";
private const string OLEACC = "Oleacc.dll";

public static Excel.Application AppFromMainWindowHandle(int mainWindowHandle)
    {
        if (mainWindowHandle == 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Window handle cannot be 0.", nameof(mainWindowHandle));

        int childHandle = 0;
        EnumChildWindows(mainWindowHandle, NextChildWindowHandle, ref childHandle);

        var win = ExcelWindowFromHandle(childHandle);

        return win?.Application;
    }

public static Excel.Window ExcelWindowFromHandle(int handle)
    {
        Excel.Window result;
        AccessibleObjectFromWindow(handle, windowObjectId, windowInterfaceId, out result);
        return result;
    }

/// <summary>Enumerates the child windows that belong to the specified parent window by passing the handle to each child window, in turn, 
/// to an application-defined callback function. EnumChildWindows continues until the last child window is enumerated or 
/// the callback function returns false.</summary>
/// <param name="hWndParent">A handle to the parent window whose child windows are to be enumerated. If this parameter is NULL,
/// this function is equivalent to EnumWindows.</param>
/// <param name="lpEnumFunc">A point to an application-defined callback function.</param>
/// <param name="lParam">An application-defined value to be passed tot he callback function.</param>
/// <returns>The return value is not used.</returns>
[DllImport(USER32)]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(int hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, ref int lParam);

/// <summary>An application-defined callback function used with the EnumChildWindows function. 
/// It receives the child window handles.  The WNDENUMPROC type defines a pointer to this callback function.
/// EnumChildProc is a placeholder for the application-defined function name.</summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">A handle to the child window of the parent window specified in EnumChildWindows.</param>
/// <param name="lParam">The application-defined value given in EnumChildWindows.</param>
/// <returns>To continue enumeration, the callback function must return TRUE; to stop enumeration it must return FALSE.</returns>
private delegate bool EnumChildCallback(int hwnd, ref int lParam);

private static bool NextChildWindowHandle(int currentChildHandle, ref int nextChildHandle)
    {
        //  Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " - NextChildWindowHandle(" + currentChildHandle + ")");
        const string excelClassName = "EXCEL7";

        var result = true;

        var className = GetClassName(currentChildHandle);
        // Debug.WriteLine(currentChildHandle + " ClassName: " + className);
        if (className == excelClassName)
        {
            nextChildHandle = currentChildHandle;
            result = false;
        }
        //  Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff") + " - NextChildWindowHandle(" + currentChildHandle + ", ref " + nextChildHandle + ") => " + result);
        return result;
    }


/// <summary>Retrieves the address of the specified interface for the object associated with the specified window.</summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">Specifies the handle of a window for which an object is to be retrieved. 
/// To retrieve an interface pointer to the cursor or caret object, specify NULL and use the appropriate ID in dwObjectID.</param>
/// <param name="dwObjectID">Specifies the object ID. This value is one of the standard object identifier constants or a custom object ID
/// such as OBJID_NATIVEOM, which is the object ID for the Office native object model.</param>
/// <param name="riid">Specifies the reference identifier of the requested interface. This value is either IID_IAccessible or IID_Dispatch,
/// but it can also be IID_IUnknown, or the IID of any interface that the object is expected to support.</param>
/// <param name="ppvObject">Address of a pointer variable that receives the address of the specified interface.</param>
/// <returns>If successful, returns S_OK; otherwise returns E_INVALIDARG, E_NOINTERFACE, or another standard COM error code.</returns>
[DllImport(OLEACC)]
private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(int hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid, out Excel.Window ppvObject);

private const uint windowObjectId = 0xFFFFFFF0;
private static readonly byte[] windowInterfaceId = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}").ToByteArray();

#region Get class name

//Gets the name of the COM class to which the specified window belongs.
private static string GetClassName(int windowHandle)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
    GetClassName(windowHandle, buffer, 128);
    return buffer.ToString();
}

/// <summary>Retrieves the name of the class to which the specified window belongs.</summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window and, indirectly, the class to which the window belongs.</param>
/// <param name="lpClassName">The class name string.</param>
/// <param name="nMaxCount">The length of the lpClassName buffer, in characters. The buffer must be large enough to include
/// the terminating null character; otherwise, the class name string is truncated to nMaxCount-1 characters.</param>
/// <returns>If the function succeeds, the number of characters copied to the buffer not including the terminating null character;
/// otherwise 0.</returns>
[DllImport(USER32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

#endregion
```

}